# How do we invoke a DELETE method on REST webservice using protractor tool?

Tags: javascript, rest, protractor

How do we invoke a DELETE method on REST web service using protractor tool?

Answer (score 4):

Protractor is browser automation tool based on selenium. It simulates users browser interaction with a given application. Thats its scope, it cannot call rest web services on its own. You need to use explicit modules like [request](https://github.com/request/request#requestdel--requestdelete) to make such calls if you wish to do so as part of your UI test.

```
var request = require('request');
request.delete(url);
```

Comment: I would also suggest using supertest within the mocha package for testing REST services.